# PHP how to create a new multidimensional array with 1 or more of the keys are same?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following Multidimensional arrays

```
if($this->conn->row_count($sql)==true){
    while($row=$statement->fetch()){
        $problems[]=[
                    'order_id'=>$row['order_id'],
                    'details'=>['remark'=>$row['remark'],'date'=>$row['date']]
                    ];
    }
    return $problems;
}
```

And then i print it out

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($problems),'</pre>';
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 4683
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [remark] => happy
                    [date] => 2018-06-09---10:16:41am
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 4683
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [remark] => unhappy
                    [date] => 2018-06-10---03:29:00am
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 4440
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [remark] => very unhappy
                    [date] => 2018-06-10---03:34:00am
                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to **group them into a new Multidimensional Array if same order_id and join details. order_id could have more than 2 because there may more remarks on this order_id** *just like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 4683
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [remark] => happy
                    [date] => 2018-06-09---10:16:41am
                ),
                (
                    [remark] => unhappy
                    [date] => 2018-06-10---03:29:00am
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 4440
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [remark] => very unhappy
                    [date] => 2018-06-10---03:34:00am
                )

        )

)
```

**For a clearer picture, please take a look at the screenshot**

[image]

Any idea how to create a new array just like the Output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group it by an associative array. You can use `array_values` to convert the associative array into a simple array.

```
$problems = [];
if($this->conn->row_count($sql)==true){
    while($row=$statement->fetch()){
        if ( !isset( $problems[ $row['order_id'] ] ) ) {
            $problems[ $row['order_id'] ] = [
                'order_id' => $row['order_id'],
                'details' => []
            ];
        }
        $problems[ $row['order_id'] ]['details'][] = ['remark'=>$row['remark'],'date'=>$row['date']];
    }
    return array_values( $problems );
}
```